# How should i go about detecting user connections with firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm asking here because I could really find an answer elsewhere I was trying to get into firebase and I'm wondering how could I check whether a user is connected or not and things like that

for example, let's say john connects I would update his status to say online but if he lost connection how would I go about this? I'm thinking about something like a separate application that starts a trigger and if an account doesn't periodically refresh that trigger they go offline but that sounds really inefficient so I am a bit stumped. not currently using the inbuilt auth by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great explanation of how to do this in the Firebase documentation under [managing presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-presence) and also a complete [example presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample).

This is only available on the main platforms where Firebase offers a **client-side** SDK: iOS, Android, and web. Since you tagged with Python, it might not apply to you.

As far as I can see from scanning the reference documentation for the [Python Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db#reference), there is no equivalent `onDisconnect()` available.